# How to change the value of DataGridView Cell when another cell in the same row changed?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

[image]

I want to change the `Amount cell` when `Qty or Price changed`.

`Amount = Qty * Price`

I tried this code and it's always giving me ArgumentOutOfRangeException .

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dg_invoices_items.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "qty")
            {   
                dg_invoices_items[e.RowIndex, 4].Value =Convert.ToString(
                        Convert.ToInt32(dg_invoices_items[e.RowIndex, 2].Value) *
                        Convert.ToInt32(dg_invoices_items[e.RowIndex, 3].Value));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Column indexes start at 0, your column indexes are one too high.

- 1st column: 0, Product
- 2nd column: 1, Qty
- 3rd column: 2, Price
- 4th column: 3, Amount

To avoid this you can probably use named columns:

```
dg_invoices_items["Qty", e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToString(
     Convert.ToInt32(dg_invoices_items["Price", e.RowIndex].Value) *
     Convert.ToInt32(dg_invoices_items["Amount", e.RowIndex].Value));
```

Altough I cannot test any code at the moment, so this might not work.

Comment: it didn't work because dg_invoices_items[e.RowIndex, "Qty"] didn't take String arguments, although I tried to start the index from 0, and I still get the same Exception.

Comment: Should be it, but column comes first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158657.aspx

Comment: Oh you have to switch them around, column first, will edit this in my post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It works as below

```
dgvInvoice["TOTAL", e.RowIndex].Value = Convert.ToInt32(dgvInvoice["QUANTITY", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()) * Convert.ToInt32(dgvInvoice["U_PRICE", e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```